# Need Id to Upload excel sheet in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, import-from-excel

I have a feature to upload the Excel sheet data into the gridview. The data will get inserted into the child table of database.

Now, My issue here is. One of the column has a relation with the Master table.

So, untill and unless I add that column `ID` which has a relation it gives me error as

> The `Student_id` column was not supplied

Here is my code

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(email) from tbl_student_report where email=@email", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Email Id"].ToString();

    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (count > 0)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Duplicate user in the sheet, Sheet will not be uploaded..!!!');window.location ='csrstudentprogress.aspx';", true);
        continue;
    }
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_student_report(NgoId,student_id,name,email,class,attendance,english_subject_marks,math_subject_marks,academic_performance,extra_activities,social_skills,general_health,date_of_record,modified_date,status,active) VALUES(@NgoId,@student_id,@name,@email,@class,@attendance,@english_subject_marks,@math_subject_marks,@academic_performance,@extra_activities,@social_skills,@general_health,@date_of_record,@modified_date,@status,@active)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dt.Rows[i]["NgoId"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dt.Rows[i]["StudentId"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Email Id"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Class"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@attendance", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Attendance"].ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@english_subject_marks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dt.Rows[i]["English Subject Marks"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@math_subject_marks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Maths Subject Marks"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@academic_performance", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Academic Performance"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@extra_activities", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Extra Activities"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@social_skills", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Social Skills"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@general_health", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["General Health"].ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_of_record", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Date Of Record"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Modified Date"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Active"].ToString();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Sheet uploaded successfully');window.location ='csrstudentprogress.aspx';", true);
}
```

Please suggest what to do in this case, because User will not add `student_id` in the excel sheet and  upload.

I am using `sql-server 2008`

How to achieve this ??

Comment: Why not just get the Id you need? Is there some reason you can't run a query to select the id based on the information you have at hand?

Comment: @Pseudonym: I didn't got you clearly. By the way which query u talking about.

Comment: I am talking about adding a query you write to access the Id column you need.

Comment: @Pseudonym: Also, I will be uploading bulks of data in the excel sheet. how will I write the query for that too ?

Comment: @Pseudonym: Can you help me with that query, as I am bit lacking in `sql`

Comment: Same way you wrote the other queries? It seems like you're asking for someone to write the code for you which isn't what this site is about. However to try and answer your question you need to use the information you have in the upload to run a select statement to pull the id you need

Comment: I have found this to be a good tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: @Pseudonym: Thanks a lot for that, I am trying to achieve that. it would be better if you give some logical ideas..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done by trying myself like below:-

*Helper class*

```
public static DataTable GetUserIdByName(string userName,string userType)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_User WHERE Username=@Username AND UserType=@UserType", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userType;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

And calling the Class in the Export function did the job:-

```
DataTable table = GeneralHelper.GetUserIdByName(Session["User"].ToString(), Session["UserType"].ToString());

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string StudentId = GetNgoIdStudentId(dt.Rows[i]["Email Id"].ToString());
                        if (StudentId != null)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_student_report(student_id,name,emailid,class,attendance,english_subject_marks,math_subject_marks,academic_performance,extra_activities,social_skills,general_health,date_of_record,modified_date,status,active) VALUES(@student_id,@name,@emailid,@class,@attendance,@english_subject_marks,@math_subject_marks,@academic_performance,@extra_activities,@social_skills,@general_health,@date_of_record,@modified_date,@status,@active)", con);

                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = table.Rows[0]["NgoId"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = StudentId;

                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Email Id"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Class"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@attendance", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Attendance"].ToString();

                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@english_subject_marks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dt.Rows[i]["English Subject Marks"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@math_subject_marks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Maths Subject Marks"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@academic_performance", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Academic Performance"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@extra_activities", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Extra Activities"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@social_skills", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Social Skills"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@general_health", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dt.Rows[i]["General Health"].ToString();

                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i]["Date Of Record"].ToString()))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_of_record", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_of_record", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Date Of Record"].ToString();
                            }
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i]["Modified Date"].ToString()))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Modified Date"].ToString();
                            }
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = dt.Rows[i]["Active"].ToString();

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            con.Close();

                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Sheet uploaded successfully');window.location ='csrstudentprogress.aspx';", true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Student not found');", true);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Error
                    }
                }
            }
```